# regex pattern test evaluating as true for everything

Tags: regex, typescript

I have the following regex named 'pattern' that I am testing to try to restrict an input to only numbers. Why are both `pattern.test("a")` and `pattern.test("1")` returning true?

```
const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
if (!pattern.test(event.target.value)) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");
}
```

Comment: What is `event.target.value` string, number?

Comment: a string from an input box

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/` matches an alphanumeric only string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expressions `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/` matches character ranges a-z, A-Z, 0-9. This will match any alphanumeric character. Adding the `*` means any number of times including zero. Meaning an empty string will also match.

If you want to match numeric and empty string only use `/^[0-9]*$/`.

If you want to match numeric only use `/^[0-9]+$/`.

Comment: ...where `''` represents an empty string... not the character `"`. I had to do a double-take.

Comment: edited that. That was confusing.